# How to prevent "Clear scrollback & reset" from breaking ZSH history in Konsole?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, konsole

When I do the "Clear scrollback & reset" command in Konsole, while using ZSH (with Oh-My-Zsh), the latter loses ability to search backward in history using up arrow key.

I.e. when I print a prefix for desired command in prompt the up-key usually shows the last command with this prefix. But after reset it simply shows the previous command with no regard to the prefix I entered.

Simple example:

1. ➜  ~ <kbd>type</kbd> prefix_ <kbd>Up</kbd>
2. ➜  ~ prefix_command *(good)*
3. ➜  ~ just_last_command *(bad)*

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this comment in KDE's bug tracker](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=238883#c3), that behavior appears to be intentional:

> The terminal emulator has a set of state information […] 'reset' puts all this back to the state of the terminal when it was first started.
>
> The main reason you'd have to use reset is if the terminal starts behaving strangely.

If you want to clear the scrollback only, without resetting the terminal, use View → Clear Scrollback. Or if you just want to clear the screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>.